bash + jq: trying to read two json files and structure a new one
I have the following json files:
common.json
{
    "common": {
        "Hello": "ABC"
    },
    "east": {
        "Direction": "East"
    },
    "west": {
        "Direction": "West"
    }
}

pi.json
{
    "common": {
       "MyUri": "www.myuri.com"
    },
    "east": {
        "App-Env": "my-pi",
        "SentinelValue": 1713311902
    },
    "west": {
        "App-Env": "my-piw",
        "SentinelValue": 1713311902
    }
}

basically I want to create a new json file where everything from "east" key of common.json + "common" key of common.json + the "common" key of pi.json + the "east" key of pi.json are moved to one json file.
I have the following script that is not working the way I thought it would:
  jq_input_files=("common.json" "pi.json")

  jq --slurp 'map({
                 ((.common | keys_unsorted[])): .common[],
                 ((.east | keys_unsorted[])): .east[]
             }) | add' "${jq_input_files[@]}" > "test.json"

The content of test.json from this script is:
{
  "MyUri": "www.myuri.com",
  "App-Env": my-pi,
  "SentinelValue": 1713311902
}

The output I wanted for test.json is:
{
  "MyUri": "www.myuri.com",
  "App-Env": 1713311902,
  "SentinelValue": 1713311902,
  "Hello": "ABC",
  "Direction": "East"
}

The two main issues I cant figure out:

It seems that nothing is being pulled from my common.json file even though both files are passed in.
It seems that App-Env is now being updated with the same value as my sentinelValue which I do not want to happen.



everything from "east" key of common.json + "common" key of common.json + the "common" key of pi.json + the "east" key of pi.json

Are there always two inputs or could there be more? Also, does the order of addition matter? Note that in case of collision, the latter overwrites the former.
If order matters, and you have two inputs only, just address them after --slurping them into an array by using first and last (or .[0] and .[1]):
jq -s 'first.east + first.common + last.common + last.east'

Demo
Alternatively, consider using input to access the second input (note that there's no need to --slurp with input):
jq '.east + .common + (input | .common + .east)'

Demo
With more than two inputs, use inputs instead to address all of the remaining inputs at once, and reduce to iterate over them. Note that this way, you only control the order of the first input as well as collectively that of all the others.
jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.east + .common; . + $i.common + $i.east)'

Demo
If there's just one relevant order (or it doesn't matter at all), you can return to --slurp, map, and add:
jq -s 'map(.east, .common) | add'

Demo

I will try this.  How would I do this by passing in two files?  Maybe I am not fully understanding how first and last correspond to the files.

Just pass them as arguments (first and last are just keywords within the jq filter). Taking your own example: jq_input_files=("common.json" "pi.json"); jq …(options and filter from above)… "${jq_input_files[@]}" > "test.json".

You might want to try jq -s '.' common.json pi.json to see what --slurp does by itself. Then, replace the . with just first to see what that does. Also try out last instead. To understand why input(s) is usually performing better than using --slurp, have a look at this merge example.

If you want want .east and .west
You can use --slurpfile to name your json files. -n is needed since you're naming and not passing files
jq -n --slurpfile common common.json --slurpfile pi pi.json \
  '($common[] * $pi[]) as $combined|$combined|del(.common)|map_values(.+$combined.common)'

with comments:
# merge keys from both files and bind to variable $combined
($common[] * $pi[]) as $combined
|$combined|del(.common)
# update every key to include $combined.common 
|map_values(.+$combined.common)

Output
{
  "east": {
    "Direction": "East",
    "App-Env": "my-pi",
    "SentinelValue": 1713311902,
    "Hello": "ABC",
    "MyUri": "www.myuri.com"
  },
  "west": {
    "Direction": "West",
    "App-Env": "my-piw",
    "SentinelValue": 1713311902,
    "Hello": "ABC",
    "MyUri": "www.myuri.com"
  }
}

